# Should TcpClient be used for this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, sockets, tcpclient

I have to communicate with an iPhone. I have its IP Address and the port (obtained via Bonjour).

I need to send a header that is “0x50544833” (or similar, It’s an HEX number), then the size of the data (below) and then the data itself.

The data is just a string that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>clientName</key>
        <string>XXX</string>
        <key>clientService</key>
        <string>0be397e7-21f4-4d3c-89d0-cdf179a7e14d</string>
        <key>registerCode</key>
        <string>0000</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The requirement also says that I must send the data in little endian format (which I think is the default for Intel anyway).

So it would be: hex_number + size of data + string_with_the_above_xml.

I need to send that to the iPhone and read the response.

What would be, according to your experience, the best way to send this data (and read the response)?

**update**: I didn’t write the iPhone software. It uses Tcp/Ip. The port depends upon the Operating System, but I’ve seen it ranging from 57xxx to 60xxxx, not always. The Mac version of this software uses Tcp/Ip. I have no access to its source code, but I am in contact with its developer, who explained me the format of the data I need to send and then, once the Bonjour service was resolved, “open a socket and …”

Comment: What software at the iPhone end is listening for your data?  Is it something you wrote?  Or as web server or something else?  The answer to your question is dictated by what protocol the iPhone is expecting you to use.

Comment: The iPhone software wasn’t written by me, but I am in contact with its developer. It doesn’t use other than TCP/IP (there’s a Mac version for the software I’m “porting”). According to the developer: “Once you have the service resolved, open a socket and …”.

Comment: Thee is no little endian for strings that are not unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use TcpClient for this scenario. It will work perfectly in this case.